# Failed to Kill Process in SQL 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, process, kill

I have a process with the following information, and i execute the kill process to kill this id, and it return me "Only user processes can be killed."

```
SPID:11
Status:BACKGROUND
Login:sa
HostName: . 
BlkBy: . 
DBName: SAFEMIG 
Command:CHECKPOINT
```

Normally, all the session to login to this server, it should have a HostName which display our PC name, but this connection is with a dot, so not sure who is executing what process that have this connection.

I execute `dbcc inputbuffer(11)`
It return me"EventType= No Event, Parameters = 0 and EventInfo=Null"

Appreciate for any help\advice on this problem!

Comment: The dot represents localhost.

Answer (score 4):

That's an internal system process, it handles writing updates to the database files; it won't let you kill it since it is vital for the workings of SQL server.

Comment: Understand. Thanks for your fast reply.

Comment: The "user" SPIDs start at 50, BTW